# Undefined index for variable after moving from Debian to Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I've been running my web app on Debian just fine, I had to move the system over to Ubuntu 16.04 for other reasons but I am having issues after setting up LAMP.

On all frontend pages in my web app the following code is at the top of the page. For reference let's say this page is called..

> login.php:

```
<?php
if (session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($varsloaded)){
    require '/var/www/html/wa/vars.php';
}
?>
html here...
```

Variables are loaded if they were not previously set from..

> vars.php:

```
if (session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
$varsloaded = 1;
$directory = "/var/www/html/wa";
$db_name = "name";
$db_user = "user";
etc....
```

However on the page load the following error is produced for all session variables.

> Undefined index: directory in /var/www/html/wa/login.php on line n

This doesn't make sense to me as there was no issue before switching to Ubuntu 16.04. I was running PHP 5.4 on Debian so swapped to 5.4 on Ubuntu also and am still having this issue.

Cheers in advance.

EDIT:

As MasterRoot24 pointed out, I have no need to set these in a session. So I have changed the code to be just variables and not SESSION variables. The *same issue* still occurs! There is no require fail on the vars.php page so it must load, but none of the variables are recognized.

Comment: This doesn't help you answer your question, but why are you storing your DB access credentials in the session?

Comment: Could you suggest another way of fetching variables from one page into another? There's no security issue with this, correct?

Comment: Environment variables, config file or include a file containing them. There's no reason why database credentials should be in the sessions, not unless you want someone to find them and compromise your DB.

Comment: @MasterRoot24 I'll just go with including variables. Not sure why I hadn't done that before... Cheers

Comment: What is `line n`? it looks like you are trying to do something like `$array['directory']` where it doens't exist. It can be your new server has a different setting for showing notices (or a newer php version), and you are checking for `$_session['directory']` (for instance) without checking `isset` first.

Comment: @Nanne I only used n to say wherever the variables are called. If you check my updated question you'll see even without using arrays I'm still having the same issue. I'm not checking for isset because it should always be set when loading the page.

Comment: There is a specific line of code in your `login.php` that causes this error. You  are not showing this line. If you'd show the line I suspect we would see something using an array, because you have an index error. Even if it isn't that, just show us the line from the error. The actual code that produces it.

Comment: @Nanne there were multiple instances of the error and they were simply where the variable was called. Pretty simple, had no need to show that. Problem solved anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

Case closed. vars.php file was started incorrectly `<? instead of <?php`.